# Chinese postman problem, but criteria = visit each vetex at least once

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Chinese postman problem, but where the postman have to visit each vetex at least once.

Is there a name for this problem?

What is the ideal algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: @YuvalFilmus "where the person has to visit each vetex **at least** once", not exactly once.

Comment: TSP allows visiting each vertex as many times as you want. Just use the shortest distance metric on your graph.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus How do I use the "shortest distance metric" on my graph?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be an edge-weighted graph. Create a new graph $G'$ in which the weight of the edge $(x,y)$ is the cost of the shortest path between $x$ and $y$ in $G$. The problem you are interested in is the traveling salesman problem (TSP) on $G'$.

Comment: What is (x,y)? Do you mean I should set all weights to be the same as the smallest weight in the graph?

Comment: Here $(x,y)$ is the name of the edge connecting vertex $x$ to vertex $y$. Its weight should be the cost of the shortest path from $x$ to $y$ in $G$.

Comment: Usually the weights will be different for different edges.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but how can this help me? What am I supposed to do after that?

Comment: It’s an extremely well-known problem. There’s a lot of information about it out there.